# SUM with calculated filed - DAX query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to calculate sum from a calculated field

```
sum(Productions201801.Piece * Item.Factor) (sql code)
```

This is the DaxQuery for calculate simple the Sum. All table are in directly ralation with the Fact Table (Productions201801)

```
EVALUATE CALCULATETABLE (
 SUMMARIZE (
     Productions201801,
     Times[TimeID],
     Color[Code],
     st[Name],
     OOR[OOCode],
     "Qty", SUM ( Productions201801[Pieces] )
 ),
 st[Name] = "Bor1",
 OOR[OOcode] = "OO-1" ) ORDER BY
 [TimeID],
 [Code],
```

Now I want to modify the dax query for SUM value this

```
SUM ( Productions201801[Pieces] * Item[Factor])
```

but Item table is not directly related with table Productions201801, is realted with table OOR by Id filed.

Someone can help me to find the right solution?

Add Realtion image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd6Q4.png)

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the relationships of the tables you mention?

Comment: Added image link

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this since I don't have the tables your working with, but I believe you should be able to replace `SUM(Productions201801[Pieces])` with something like the following:

```
SUMX(Productions201801, Productions201801[Pieces] * Item[Factor])
```

Comment: I Alexis, thank you for your suggestion but sql engine give me error becouse there is not direct relationship between table Productions201801 and Item table.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a select in a select...

```
SELECT sum(mult) FROM (SELECT Productions201801.Pieces, Item.Factor, 
Productions201801.Pieces*Item.Factor as mult
FROM Productions201801
INNER JOIN ITEM ON Productions201801.id=Item.id);
```

Comment: I want the DAX query, with the same result set: Times[TimeID], Color[Code], st[Name], OOR[OOCode], "Qty"